# Associative property with DBL_MAX and DBL_MIN?

Tags: c, double

Can someone explain me why is this happening:

1+2+DBL_MAX-DBL_MIN = 0 and 1+DBL_MAX-DBL_MIN+2=3?

Comment: because in the float point arithmetics a + b + c does not have to be equal to c + b + a and you have the UB here as well - so any result is good.

Comment: What does it mean UB?